# Around 00-01 Fide had a great online arena. What happened to that?

Tags: fide, online

I remember this from the days entering high school ;) Fide.com has this very well made online game room, much like yahoo's in terms of functionality, but much cleaner and with some funky rating system (started at 0 and 20-30 was strong!).

I also remember that the best players there, or those who won some online tournament there, would play on the actual Fide finals -- back in the days when it was knock-out 128 or something like that.

I am just wondering when this got cancelled and the website got crapped into what it's now.

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20010707032253/http://www.fide.com/cgi-bin/material/main.pl) is what it looked like then. Just wondering if there is an easy way to get to a top tournament today.

Comment: The site still exists. http://arena.fide.com/ . It's not free though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually FIDE publish a new chess platform named FIDE Online Area (http://arena.myfide.net/) . Furthermore there are several tournaments to encourage chess players to use this arena such as ;

- The 1st FIDE World Online Amateur Blitz Championship 2015
- The 1st FIDE World Online Junior Blitz Championship 2015
- The 1st FIDE World Online Women Blitz Championship 2015.

Instead, ICC(Internet Chess Club) is the most visited online chess area among professional chess players. (http://www.chessclub.com/)

Comment: Interesting! Can you give a reference for your claim about ICC?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the link ahead, titled players rate is very high on ICC.http://www6.chessclub.com/help/titles